# Prove directly that if A and B are uncountable then A ∪ B is also uncountable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove directly that if sets $A$ and $B$ are uncountable then $A \cup B$ is also uncountable.

My study group has been stuck on this problem for a while. Every direct proof we make seems to have circular reasoning.

Though we have found a contrapositive proof defining $f$ to be that which maps the naturals to $A \cup B$ and $g(n)$ to be the $n$-th element of $f$ which is an element of $A$.

Comment: In Dugundji's *Topology,* result II.7.4 states that if $A\subset X$ then the cardinality of $A$ is at most the cardinality of $X.$ By definition II.7.3 of the same work, the cardinality of $A$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $X$ if there is an injection $A \rightarrow X.$ But $A$ is a subset of $X.$

Comment: Of course I meant $A$ is a subset of $A \cup B$, not $X$. Sorry about that.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "uncountable" (if it refers to countability, then exactly what is that definition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $B \setminus A$ is uncountable.  There are injections $f: \omega_1 \to A, g: \omega_1 \to B \setminus A$.  Use $f$ and $g$ to define an injection $h: \omega_1+\omega_1 \to A \cup B$ and then use an explicit bijection between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1+\omega_1$ to end up with an injection from $\omega_1$ to $A \cup B$.  This injective map shows that $A \cup B$ can't be countable.

If $B \setminus A$ is countable, just use an injection $g: \omega \to B \setminus A$ and then let $f'(\alpha) = f(\omega + \alpha)$.  A similar trick works if $B \setminus A$ is finite.

**Edit:**  Now that I think about this some more, I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Let $f: \omega_1 \to A$ be an injection.  Then $f$ is also an injection from $\omega_1$ to $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a bijection $f\colon A\cup B\to \Bbb N$. Show that $f|_A\colon A\to \Bbb N$ is injective, and proceed depending on your definition of cardinality.

Comment: That looks like a proof by contradiction.  Perhaps "directly" precludes that

Comment: I mean, I think most proofs that sets are uncountable are by definition going to be proofs by contradiction. Unless OP specifies that $A$ and $B$ have cardinality of the reals, all you can really say is that they cannot be put into bijections with $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Henry, how else could you prove that an infinite set $S$ is uncountable? By definition, you have to show that there is no bijection $S\to\Bbb N$.

Comment: You can probably show $A\cup B$ is in bijection with either $A$ or $B$, but I'm not sure how hard that would be, and it probably would require uncountable choice.

Comment: Would defining a surjection from $A\cup B$ to $A$ be direct? Or can we not use that a surjection from $C$ to $D$ implies $|C|\ge |D|$?

Comment: @ElliotG, there is no need. Henry is just making waves.

Comment: @TonyK By showing there's an injection $h: \omega_1 \to S$.